# Error when using method "no Known class method for selector"

Tags: objective-c

The class "PlayingCardDeck" inherits "Deck" class can not put the method

```
- (void) addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
```

Xcode accuses me the following error:
no Known class method for selector 'addCard:atTop'

Class: PlayingCardDeck

```
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCardDeck

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        for(NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits]){
            for (NSUInteger rank = 1; rank <= [PlayingCard maxRank]; rank++){
                PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
                card.rank = rank;
                card.suit = suit;
                [PlayingCardDeck addCard:card atTop:NO];
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Class: Deck

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface Deck()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;

@end


@implementation Deck

- (NSMutableArray *)cards
{
    if(!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _cards;
}

- (void) addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
    if(atTop){
        [self.cards insertObject:card atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [self.cards addObject:card];
    }
}

- (Card *)drawRandomCard
{
    Card *randomCard = nil;

    if(self.cards.count){
        unsigned index = arc4random() % self.cards.count;
        randomCard = self.cards[index];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }

    return randomCard;
}

@end
```

thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `-addCard:atTop:` is an **instance** method. It must be sent to an instance of a class, not the class itself. This line:

```
[PlayingCardDeck addCard:card atTop:NO];
```

is attempting to send it to the class `PlayingCardDeck`, not any instance of that class. That's what the error is trying to tell you.

Since that code is in the `-init` method of the `PlayingCardDeck` class, you probably meant to send the message to `self`:

```
[self addCard:card atTop:NO];
```